# How can I create a simple counter as a webapp with increase and decrease buttons using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I've tried to create a simple counter with increase in decrease buttons, but I cannot go any further.

The code I've been stuck with is:

for code.gs

```
let count = 0;
const counter = document.getElementById("count");

function onDec() {
  count = count-1;
  counter.textContent = count;
}

function onInc() {
  count = count+1;
  counter.textContent = count;
}
```

and for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <h2><span id="count">0</span></h2>
    <button id="decBtn" class="button" onclick="onDec()">-</button>
    <button id="incBtn" class="button" onclick="onInc()">+</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've realised recently what is missing, is doGet() function in code.gs. But so far adding this didn't solve the problem. I know I'm missing something simple and important, but I'm completely lost right now.

Comment: Do you want to keep the `count` on the server (where `code.gs` runs) or on the client (as implied by `document.getElementById("count")`)?

Comment: This is Google Apps Script, so I have like a console with files, which I deploy later as a WebApp, as far as I understand. Not sure how they're deployed. I only remember they're deployed on cloud by Google. I think they should be in one place, but Google suggest there should be doGet() function in each script. And so far what I've seen from tutorials for GAS. This function is indeed included mostly. I also added it to the code as I've said on the comment below. But it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: You can either deploy a pure HTML + Javascript page where everything happens on the browser. Or you can deploy a service where the HTML page makes a request to Google Apps Script in order to increase the counter _on the server_. You should understand the difference between these two and decide which you want. (Pure HTML + Javascript is rather boring, and does not need Google Apps Script.)

Comment: @isherwood, I'm not happy how the title was edited because it asks for advice for ANY webapp, not specifically for Google Apps Script, which has some environmental differences that are crucial for the answer. I asked for advice specifically for GAS, so I don't understand why it was kicked out of the title. Especially I was looking for answers, found similar questions like the title is right now, but the answers didn't work in my exact situation. Also I don't want here to ask SPECIFIC question, because I'm not sure what can be the exact issue. That's why the title is pretty much generic.

Comment: See [ask], then revise as you see fit. Don't tack on tags, and it's not helpful to announce that you're new to a topic. Most of us are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer that actually involves a Google Apps Script. The tricky part is storing the `count` somewhere. It cannot be just a global Javascript variable, because that would be re-initialized with every request. Instead, it is a global variable (which can be read by the `index.html` template) that is read from and written to the script cache, where it survives for 6 hours. (You cannot expect to get longer-lasting storage for free.)

Code.gs

```js
var count;
function doGet(request) {
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  count = cache.get("count") || 0;
  if (request.parameters.dec) count--;
  else if (request.parameters.inc) count++;
  cache.put("count", count, 21600);
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html").evaluate();
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>" target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2><span id="count"><?= count ?></span></h2>
      <a id="decBtn" class="button" href="?dec">-</a>
      <a id="incBtn" class="button" href="?inc">+</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comparing this answer to the others should give you an idea of the difference between server- and client-side programming.

Comment: For my use I think 6 hours gonna be more than enough, especially for what I plan to use it. Thank you for your whole input into this topic. And yeah I think I see the difference you're talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly include the html without `include` function like this.  This is a working live snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
<h2><span id="count">0</span></h2>
<button id="decBtn" class="button" onclick="onDec()">-</button>
<button id="incBtn" class="button" onclick="onInc()">+</button>
</div>
  <script>

let count = 0;
const counter = document.getElementById("count");

function onDec() {
  count = count-1;
  counter.textContent = count;
}

function onInc() {
  count = count+1;
  counter.textContent = count;
}

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

## You have not included the script in your HTML

In order to execute the script, you need to add a `<script>` element into your HTML document.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="code.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <h2><span id="count">0</span></h2>
    <button id="decBtn" class="button" onclick="onDec()">-</button>
    <button id="incBtn" class="button" onclick="onInc()">+</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice I've modified your filename to `code.js` and I've used the `defer` keyword to ensure the code runs *after* the HTML loads.

Comment: I cannot specify "code.js" because Google Apps Script force me to use *.gs filename. I cannot change that. Thank you for your answer